# Using environment variable in a file path

Tags: c#, path, environment-variables, folderbrowserdialog

I've got an environment variable set that points to a specific folder (call it MYFOLDER for example). When typing in `%MYFOLDER%\SubFolder` into windows explorer the subfolder appears. However, when I pass `SelectedPath = @"%MYFOLDER%\SubFolder";` to a `FolderBrowserDialog`, it doesn't work.

I tried using `Path.GetFullPath(..)`, but this seems to return the bin folder of the executable (while debugging in VS) with %MYFOLDER% on the end, instead of the path I'd expect.

Anyone know how to get it to use the environment variable properly?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Expand it first:

```
string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(value);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx

Comment: I also discovered: restart visual studio when you add the variable!

Comment: Just to add: the path came through pre-expanded after having restarted Visual Studio so `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables` wasn't needed after all.