# Reading a file path from text file with environment variable in C#

Tags: c#, environment-variables, text-files

I am trying to read a text file with file paths, but the problem I'm having is I want to add environment variable in it with the specific file path, how should I achieve that? I tried to do %example123%+\XML\sample.xml but c# is not recognizing the variable instead it's reading it as a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options, per your example:

`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("example123") + @"\XML\sample.xml"`

or

`System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%example123%\XML\sample.xml")`

Something to note from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348003/using-environment-variable-in-a-file-path?rq=1) is that Visual Studio must be restarted before the variable is recognized if you have set the variable using `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()`.

Answer (score 5):

These two methods should help you in getting or setting environment variables.

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ()
```

and

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()
```

Either use them in your path variable or declare it separately, whichever is more readable.

Note: When using the SetEnvironmentVariable() sometimes you would have to restart visual studio to be able to read the environment variable after creating it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for %AppData%

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData");
```