# How can I resolve the path of a command (e.g.- gacutil) progmatically?

Tags: c#, cmd, environment-variables, gac

I need to progmatically call gacutil to uninstall some binaries from GAC.

To be able to use gacutil commands from cmd I had to add the gacutil path to the PATH variable. But now that I'm trying to run gacutil from code, I need to dynamically resolve the path of the gacutil to be able to start the process. But I couldn't find a way to resolve the gacutil path yet. Is there any?

I did try expanding the PATH environment variable like suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348003/using-environment-variable-in-a-file-path) answer, but since PATH variable has multiple directories on it (separated by semicolons), there's no simple way to resolve the gacutil path.

But obviously when I type gacutil in cmd it somehow resolves the path searching through all the available directories in the PATH variable. How can I make that happen from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If path is specified in PATH environment variable, you do not need to know the path:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "gacutil";
p.Start();    
//it automatically resolves path basin on PATH environment variable
```

.

Comment: I cannot use UseShellExecute=true, because I need to redirect the standardoutputs

Comment: Thanks! I was getting Exception- "The system cannot find the file specified." but restarting the VS solved the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Using this, start it using Process.Start and read the output:

```
WHERE gacutil
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if it's in the path you don't need to search it as @nopeflow answered. But if you really want to get the path of any file in the `PATH` environment variable,you could do something like this:

```
string[] PathDirs = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").Split(';');
string GACdir="";
foreach (string path in PathDirs)
{
     if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(path,"gacutil.exe")))
     {
            GACdir=path;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all of the executables in the PATH, the following `cmd.exe` script will identify them.

```
@SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@SET EXITCODE=1

:: Needs an argument.

@IF "x%1"=="x" (
    @ECHO Usage: %0 ^<progName^>
    GOTO TheEnd
)

@set newline=^


@REM Previous two (2) blank lines are required. Do not change!

@REM Ensure that the current working directory is first
@REM because that is where DOS looks first.
@PATH=.;!PATH!

@FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ("%PATH:;=!newline!%") DO @(
    @IF EXIST %%i\%1 (
        @ECHO %%i\%1
        @SET EXITCODE=0
    )

    @FOR /F "tokens=*" %%x in ("%PATHEXT:;=!newline!%") DO @(
        @IF EXIST %%i\%1%%x (
            @ECHO %%i\%1%%x
            @SET EXITCODE=0
        )
    )
)

:TheEnd
@EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```